Why does calling an async actor function in a MainActor result in a compiler error in Swift 6 to file a bug?
I have the following MainActor class:
import Foundation
import os

@MainActor
public class UserData: ObservableObject {
    let userDataLogger = Logger(
        subsystem:
            "com.author.app",
        category: "Model")
    
    // PDF methods
    var pdfManager = PDFManager()
    @Published var allPDFs: [PDFModel] = []
    
    func loadPDFs() {
        Task {
            do {
                let pdfFiles = try await pdfManager.fetchAllPDFs()
                self.allPDFs = pdfFiles.map { PDFModel(fileName: $0.lastPathComponent, url: $0) }
            } catch {
                userDataLogger.error("Error fetching PDF files: \(String(describing: error))")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func addPDF(data: Data, fileName: String) {
        Task {
            do {
                try await pdfManager.savePDF(data: data, fileName: fileName)
                loadPDFs()
            } catch {
                userDataLogger.error("Error saving PDF: \(String(describing: error))")
            }
        }
    }
}

and the following actor:
public actor PDFManager {
    func savePDF(data: Data, fileName: String) async throws {
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        
        do {
            try data.write(to: fileURL)
            print("Saved PDF to \(fileURL)")
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    }
    
    func fetchAllPDFs() async throws -> [URL] {
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let pdfFiles = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
            .filter { $0.pathExtension == "pdf" }
        
        return pdfFiles
    }
}


The Swift compiler complains that Pattern that the region based isolation checker does not understand how to check. Please file a bug on both:
let pdfFiles = try await pdfManager.fetchAllPDFs()

try await pdfManager.savePDF(data: data, fileName: fileName)

I don’t really understand what I’m doing wrong to be getting this error. Are there any workarounds?

Why is PDFManager an actor? Are you going to access it from multiple threads? If you are going to acsess if from one thread it isn't nedded to be an actor. AND since you are only fetching all pdf's you will always need to acsess it after adding/saving an pdf. In your case its like making an var optional that is never going to be optional because it may become optional somehow.

And I dont get the error.

Have you tried enabling Swift 6 in your project? @Radioactive

Also turns out it’s a known bug in Swift 6 and the Xcode beta. The workaround is to do ‘let pdfManager = pdfmanager’ right before calling ‘await’

The data class should only hold the data it shouldn't have any async funcs. Those should be in a controller struct. Then from your .task modifier call the async func and pass in the object you want it to update, eg
.task {
    await controller.asyncFunc(dataStore)
}

Or you can just return results and store in @State then you don't even need the object.
